# Mounting and unmounting in same shell script results in error

Tags: shell-script, shell, mount, tar, unmounting

I need to mount a volume, `tar` the contents of the mounted volume and unmount that mounted volume, in a single shell script.

So I coded as,

```
$ cat sample.sh
sudo mount -o loop Sample.iso /tmp/mnt
cd /tmp/mnt
tar-cvf /tmp/sample.tar *
sudo umount /tmp/mnt
```

I got the error `umount: /tmp/mnt: device is busy.`

So I checked the

```
$ lsof /tmp/mnt
```

It outputs the current "sh" file. So I convinced myself, `/tmp/mnt` is busy in the current script (in this case, sample.sh).

Is there any way around for (mount, tar, unmount) in the same script ?

***P.S*** : I'm able to unmount the /tmp/mnt volume once the script finishes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to exit the directory to unmount it, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -o loop Sample.iso /tmp/mnt
cd /tmp/mnt
tar -cvf /tmp/sample.tar *
#Got to the old working directory. **NOTE**: OLDPWD is set automatically.
cd $OLDPWD
#Now we're able to unmount it. 
sudo umount /tmp/mnt
```

That is it.

Comment: I'm not sure how portable this is, but in `bash` you can use `-` as an alias of `$OLDPWD` in `cd` : `cd -` will bring you back to the previous dir.

Comment: Or just `cd /`. Since the script then exits, it doesn't really matter which directory you change to, as long as it isn't `/tmp/mnt`.

Comment: There's no reason to use `$OLDPWD` or `cd -` or anything like that. Just `cd /`. The `cd` invocation only affects the subshell the script is running in, and all we need is to leave `/tmp/mnt`. Any target will do since, once the script exits, we will always be in whatever directory we were in when the script was launched.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy and @terdon Just in case there were some ill effects, I wouldn't want to `cd /` and potentially do something in `/`.  Instead, I'd `cd /tmp`

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini If it *needs* to do something else, it should go where it needs to do that. If something else unforseen happens that was not intended, `/tmp` is probably the least-bad place for it to happen.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini The easiest way to do that is provided by @Kusalananda: `( cd /tmp/mnt && tar -cvf /tmp/sample.tar * )`
No explicit cd required because the subshell terminates as soon as the tar command exits.  To be clear, I'm not arguing that `cd /tmp` is superior to returning whence it came; I'm only objecting to `cd /` as a bad practice.

Comment: I understand that is a subshell and when the shell scripts exit the interactive shell will be still on the original directory, that is not the point! Sometimes shell scripts  creates temporary or static files in the working dir and for some reason it will need to use this files again during the sub shell execution, so to do not back to the old working directory will make the script broken, because it will not be able to found its files anymore. Tipically scripts do not end in that simple...the best practice when its is possible, is that scripts has a reserved work temporary dir declared.

Comment: using lazy method `umount -l /mnt/crap` (my fav is being lazy) worked for me.

Comment: Lazy umount is just telling the kernel to do unmount when it's able to. It works.

Comment: @GeneCode  You're correct. And then when the scripts exits, it will be unmounted interesting, but if the script is still working, after that, already expecting the device is already unmounted? For example: Showing a message, you can remove your device right now, is already unmounted (but the device is still busy because the script is running in the directory isnt?), or if a external program are running, your script will never warn you with umount -l. Still, it will never unmount if it is still busy, it will look like unmounted, like I say.

Comment: I do not have your situation yet so it works for me. Maybe it will be bad for other people doing other things as you said. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: For some cases umount -l can be a great idea, after all I never thinked in that way, so Thank You for sharing this too!

Answer (score 11):

The device is "busy" since you just used `cd` to move into it.  You can not unmount the partition of the current working directory (of any process, in this case the shell).

Your script:

```
sudo mount -o loop Sample.iso /tmp/mnt
cd /tmp/mnt
tar -cvf /tmp/sample.tar *
sudo umount /tmp/mnt
```

Modified script without the same issue:

```
sudo mount -o loop Sample.iso /tmp/mnt
( cd /tmp/mnt && tar -cvf /tmp/sample.tar * )
sudo umount /tmp/mnt
```

Since the `cd` happens in a sub-shell, it will not affect the environment outside of it, and the current directory at the time of the `umount` will be wherever you were when you executed the script.

This is a very common shell construct, i.e. to do

```
( cd dir && somecommand )
```

It is a lot cleaner (and clearer) than trying to `cd` somewhere and then back again, especially when having to go into multiple directories during the course of one script.

With the `&&` it also means that the command won't be executed if the `cd` for some reason failed.  In your script, if the `mount` failed, you would still create a `tar` archive of an empty (?) directory, for example, which may not be what you would want.

A shorter variant that makes use of the `-C` flag of `tar`:

```
sudo mount -o loop Sample.iso /tmp/mnt
tar -cvf /tmp/sample.tar -C /tmp/mnt .
sudo umount /tmp/mnt
```

This makes *`tar`* do the `cd` internally before adding the current directory (`/tmp/mnt`) to the archive. Notice, though, that this has the effect that hidden files or folders will also be added to the archive.